# Gradle template project for Cloud Endpoints Frameworks with guice

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, guice, google-cloud-endpoints

There is a [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/quickstart-frameworks-java) for Cloud Endpoints , [quckstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/gradle) for Cloud Endpoints Frameworks on App Engine and [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/migrating) for Cloud Endpoints Frameworks 2.

I was not able either to glue it together or find any templates/boilerplate code for gradle based project with latest [plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin) running Cloud Endpoints Frameworks 2 with [guice](https://github.com/google/guice) and [Objectify](https://github.com/objectify/objectify).

Can anyone shed some light on it?

Comment: Can you provide detail on the behaviors you were running into?